# Amazon api searching Streaming Video

Tags: amazon-web-services

Ok so I am trying to search Amazon through the api for movie or tv titles. I simply want to get back the list that would include if it is available, Price, if its available on prime.
The query I have works with some issues.
By specifing a searchindex of "video" it returns results for ordering the physical dics. I only want streaming results. I have looked and streaming is not a valid search index. Is there any way to do this?

I guess basically I just want to return if it available in streaming and if it is.. is it also available on prime.

Comment: I found the merchant parameter, but when set to "Amazon Video On Demand" it still includes DVD, Amazon.com, etc